# Why does my web scraper write everything into a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Complete newbie but I've managed to successfully scrape EAN numbers with Python from a list of links created by an upstream piece of code. However, my output file contains all the scraped numbers as a continuous single line instead of one EAN per line.

Here's my code - what's wrong with it? (scraped URL redacted)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import os

subpage = 1

while subpage <= 2:
    URL = "https://..." + str(subpage)
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    """writes all links under the h2 tag into a list"""
    links = []
    h2s = soup.find_all("h2")
    for h2 in h2s:
        links.append("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com" + h2.a['href'])

    """opens links from list and extracts EAN number from underlying page"""
    with open("temp.txt", "a") as output:
        for link in links:
            urllib.request.urlopen(link)
            page_2 = requests.get(link)
            soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(page_2.content, "html.parser")
            if "EAN:" in soup_2.text:
                span = soup_2.find(class_="articleData_ean")
                EAN = span.a.text
                output.write(EAN)
        subpage += 1

os.replace('temp.txt', 'EANs.txt')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output.write(EAN)` is writing each EAN without anything between them. It doesn't automatically add a separator or newline. You can add a newline: `output.write('\n')` or comma, etc. to separate them

Comment: I tinkered around with \n before posting my question, but I couldn't figure out how to properly use it. I still have that problem with your answer, because the '\n' sits where the EAN variable sits (if 'variable' is the right word here...) . How do I add it into the code above?

Comment: If `EAN` is a string you can do `output.write(EAN + '\n')`. If not, just add another line beneath your existing output and `output.write('\n')`

Comment: Thanks, that works. And it's a different question, but do you happen to know how I would need to modify the code to write the output into separate files each 500 lines long? With a systematic filenames such as "filename_001-500" ; "filename_501-1000; ... etc.?